# pass a function to property

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to know how to set a function to a method :

```
function myfunc(){
   this.method = function() {};
   this.method2 = function (){this.method();}
}
```

So that I can do this

```
obj=new myfunc();
obj.method=function(){//otherthings};
```

when method2 is executed ,the new method will be executed too.

***Update: it works just fine , No problem***

Comment: That code should work just fine..

Comment: Just like that. Did something go wrong when you tried it? Why do you think that there is an issue here?

Comment: And if you do exactly the above and then say `obj.method2();` what happens? It should work.

Comment: I'm curious why you posted before just trying it?

Comment: It's not pretty, but it should work.

Comment: i get an error method is not a function

Comment: What don't you like about it @FelixKling?

Comment: ok ok my bad -__-' this is not my real code! in my code I had a simple mistake .. thx

Comment: @Peter: I prefer the methods bound to the prototype and not inside the constructor function... but maybe it's just me ;) (and there might be use cases for the latter).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is exactly how you do it.